# Updating an is_latest column on redshift table

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm attempting to update an `is_latest` column on a redshift table grouped by `source` and `source_primary_key` with the following update statement, but getting an error that window functions are not allowed in update statements. What is the best way to go about this?

```
update my_schema.production_log
set is_latest = 
case when run_start_time = max(run_start_time) over (partition by 
source,   source_primary_key)
then ‘t’ else ‘f’
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Redshift supports a `FROM` clause in the `update` statement.  Try this:

```
update my_schema.production_log
    set is_latest = (case when run_start_time = max_run_start_time
                          then 't' else 'f'
                     end)
    from (select source, source_primary_key, max(run_start_time) as max_run_start_time
          from my_schema.production_log
          group by source, source_primary_key
         ) pl2
    where pl2.source = production_log.source and
          pl2.source_primary_key = production_log.source_primary_key;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite the query so it can join to a derived table:

```
UPDATE u
SET u.is_latest =CASE
                     WHEN u.run_start_time = j.max_time THEN 't'
                     ELSE 'f'
                 END
FROM my_schema.production_log AS u
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        source
      , source_primary_key
      , MAX( run_start_time ) max_time
    FROM my_schema.production_log
    GROUP BY
        source
      , source_primary_key
) AS j
    ON u.source = j.source
    AND u.source_primary_key = j.source_primary_key
```